# Encrypting a folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, encryption

Recently, when I tried to encrypt a folder in my external HDD, I was presented with a dialogue box as given below:
[image]
What' the difference between **Apply changes to this folder only** and **Apply changes to this folder, subfolders and files** in encrypting a folder?
If I select the first one, will the folder be accessible to others(and the files inside it)?

UPDATE:[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/607921/encrypting-a-folder) answers my question partially, but not the second part about the accessibility of the files inside that folder.

Comment: @Moab What about the second part of the question, it isn't answered in the other question?

Comment: No one will be able to access the folder/file that's encrypted except the user who created the encrypted folder/file. If you select the first option, no one will even be able to open the folder except the user who created it. This also applies to the second option too as the folder will still be encrypted.

Comment: Better to ask One question per post.

Comment: "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question,**please ask a new question**."

Comment: @RogUE - Even the second part is addressed in the answer to the duplicate question.  Any files in the folder itself will be encrypted.  Any files in folders contained within the folder would not be encrypted.  If that does not answer the question then clarify your follow-up seperate question.

Comment: @Ramhound **When you select "apply changes to this folder" only new content in the folder will be encrypted. Existing files and folders will not be encrypted.**, this is what the other question says about the second part, I think this is different from your clarification

Comment: @RogUE  If you choose "Apply changes to this folder only", folders or files you made before encryption, would be accessible to others.